# Trouble updating Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2. I downloaded the latest, 2020-05-27-raspios-buster-full-armhf.img, installed it from Linux via dd. It runs. It goes through many reboots, updating and installing software each time.  I updated software a few times via "apt-get update; apt-get upgrade" successfully, rebooting as necessary.

In the middle of yet another update, the screen went black, and the RPi halted. Attempts to reboot fail, with the green LED flashing 7 times, apparently indicating that kernel.img can't be found.

I mounted the microSD on Linux, and can see the files in /boot and /rootfs. I ran a "find" search on both partitions, but I cannot see any file called kernel.img

I've already installed the OS twice, each time ending with one of the updates crashing, and then not being able to boot. I tried another microSD from another pi, and my RPi boots just fine from that microSD, so it's not the RPi.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I bought a new card, verified that it was really from SanDisk. (Turns out the original was too, but appeared to become unusable in the middle of upgrading raspbian.)
Today, I started all over...no apt or apt-get. When the RPi updated software on its own, it suddenly rebooted, and then couldn't get up again. The green LED flashed 7 times.
I looked at the SD card on Linux. Both partitions are there, but there were no kernel files in /boot! As an experiment, I saved the 2 partitions on my Linux box. After the RPi failure, I copied the kernel*.img files to the card. Alas, it did not work. Undoubtedly, it needed other files too.

BTW, apt-get autoremove just gets rid of old dependencies, that are no longer needed. The differences between apt and apt-get are superficial, apt being created to make apt-get easier to use. Thanks for the pointer. Changing to apt will be a bit less typing. (I've been using Unix & Linux since the 1980's.)

---

This is around the 7th time I've cycled through the installation process. When the automatic, I have nothing to do with, updates happen, the RPi reboots and hangs because it can't find the kernel image! WTF?

Is there some way to mount the microSD on a Linux box and stick the right files where they're supposed to go? Automatic is NOT WORKING!

Comment: Try another SD Card

Comment: Once you have a new card I would also add for you to stop using apt-get and update. It's now suggested to use apt (better for interactive use) and full-upgrade https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md one thing that is currently odd is the need to run a `sudo apt autoremove` to take out the eeprom files if you are not on a Pi 4 - it's not mentioned in the notes linked and not an issue if left around but it's just been updated in the full-upgrade (such a waste of electrons) :-)

Comment: the fact that *It goes through **many** reboots* and you *updated software **a few times** suggests something very wrong with the SD card - because after initial image install, you'd apt update / upgrade once to get the latest of everything - it's not like Microsoft windows :p